# Código em Python - Estrutura Condicional

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como faço em Python para receber o valor do salário base e o valor das vendas desse vendedor, sendo que o salário base do funcionário deve ser de até R$700.00 com uma bonificação de 4.5% sobre suas vendas e se o volume de vendas for maior do que R$15.000,00 ganha uma bonificação de 1.2% sobre as vendas.

Por enquanto meu código está assim:

```
sal = float ("Insira salário: "()) 

ven = float ("Insira valor de vendas: "()) 

if sal <= 700 and ven >= 15000.00:

bonisal = 0.045

boniven = 0.012

calsal = (salario * bonisal) * 100

calven = (vendas * boniven) * 100
```

Comment: Fiz mais linhas, atualize a página. Agora fico na dúvida se é tudo na mesma condição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer um código simples sem ter tantas verificações você pode simplesmente usar esse código:

```py
sal = float(input('Insira o salário: '))
vendas = float(input('Insira o valor de vendas: '))
while True:
    if sal < 700:
        break
    else:
        print('Salario precisa ser positivo e até R$700')
        sal = float(input('Salário: '))

bonificacao = vendas * (4.5/100)
if ven > 150000:
    bonificacao += vendas * (1.2/100)

calcvendas = sal + bonificacao
print(calcvendas)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, realmente compreendi melhor esse código mas eu percebi que está errado na linha que possui "if ven > 15000" ao invés de "if vendas > 150000" mas meu professor ainda está em estrutura condicional e você usou a estrutura de repetição while

Comment: @SonoGoku, entendi. Vou editar a pergunta para satisfazer sua pergunta :)

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, a "função" (que é uma classe) `float` não faz leitura da entrada do programa. Ou seja, você não consegue solicitar ao usuário um valor por meio dela, para tal precisará da função `input` (`raw_input` no Python 2). Utilize a `float` apenas para definir um valor numérico a partir do valor lido. Podemos adicionar ao processo uma validação para garantir que o salário informado seja menor ou igual a 700, como informa o enunciado:

```
while True:
    try:
        salario = float(input('Informe o salário: R$ '))
        if not 0 < salario <= 700.00:
            raise ValueError('Salario precisa positivo e até 700')
        break
    except ValueError as error:
        print(error)
```

Assim será solicitado ao usuário até que ele insira um valor válido:

```
>>> Informe o salário: R$ a
could not convert string to float: 'a'
>>> Informe o salário: R$ 800
Salario precisa positivo e até 700
>>> Informe o salário: R$ 500
```

Fazemos o mesmo para o valor vendido, mas agora sem a validação do intervalo:

```
while True:
    try:
        vendas = float(input('Informe o valor em vendas: R$ '))
        break
    except ValueError as error:
        print(error)
```

Enunciado fala que há uma bonificação de 4.5% sobre o valor de venda:

```
bonificacao = 4.5 / 100
```

Mais um acréscimo de 1.2% se o valor em vendas superar 15.000:

```
if vendas > 15_000:
    bonificacao += 1.2 / 100
```

Portanto o valor final do salário será:

```
final = salario + vendas * bonificacao
```

Answer (score 1):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/calcvenda-stopt)

Minha sugestão consiste em uma função que pode receber as porcentagens para as bonificações como parametros opcionais e retorna um dicionario com os valores informados pelo usuário e os cálculos realizados.

```
def calcvendas(bnf=4.5, bnf_adicional=1.2):
    salario, vendas = -1, -1
    while salario<0 or salario>700:
        try:
            salario = float(input('Digite o salário (até 700): '))
        except ValueError as error:
          print(error) 
    while vendas<0:
        try:
            vendas = float(input('Insira o valor de vendas (>=0): '))
        except ValueError as error:
            print(error) 
    bonificacao = vendas * (bnf/100) 
    adicional = 0 if vendas <= 15000 else vendas * (bnf_adicional/100)
    return {'Salario': salario, 'Vendas': vendas, 
            'Bonificacao': bonificacao, 'Adicional': adicional, 
            'Total': salario+bonificacao+adicional}

print(calcvendas())
```

No caso do usuário ter digitado 500 para o salario e 16000 para as vendas, a saida seria:

```
{'Salario': 500.0,
 'Vendas': 16000.0,
 'Bonificacao': 720.0,
 'Adicional': 192.0,
 'Total': 1412.0}
```

Veja que no meu entendimento, no caso do vendedor atingir a meta de superar 15k de vendas, ele ganha o adicional sobre o valor da venda.

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/calcvenda-stopt)

Answer (score 0):

Brother, tô sem o Python aqui para verificar se o código tá rodando sem bugs, mas, se não entendi errado o que você pediu, esse código aqui vai funcionar:
<sup>(verifica se não tem nenhum erro de sintaxe pois eu escrevi no bloco)</sup>

```
sal = float (input('Insira o salário do vendedor (de no máximo R$ 700,00): '))  
ven = float (input('Insira o valor de vendas realizadas: '))  
if ven <= 15000:  
    sal_com_bonificação = sal +((ven/100) * 4.5)  
elif ven > 15000:  
    sal_com_bonificação = sal +((ven/100) * 1.2)  
print('O salário do vendedor que ganha {} e vendeu {} será {}'.format(sal; ven; sal_com_bonificação))
```

PS: Lembra de indentar as condições abaixo de `IF` e `ELIF`.